# If $K$ and $K'$ are extensions of the same field $F$, is every isomorphism $K \to K'$ a $F$-isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, definition, extension-field

If $K$ and $K'$ are extensions of the same field $F$, is every isomorphism $K \to K'$ a $F$-isomorphism, i.e., an isomorphism which restricts to the identity on $F$?

Comment: In the special case where $K=K'=F$, this would imply that $F$ has no non-trivial isomorphism, which is very far from true in most cases.

Comment: Good point. Should I rephrase my question as $K$ and $K'$ being strict extensions? Is that a correct phrasing?

Answer (score 2):

If there's a common subfield $\;L\neq F\;$ you can contradict that. For example, take

$$K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]2)\;,\;\;K'=\Bbb Q(i\sqrt[4]2)\;,\;\;L=\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)\;,\;\;F=\Bbb Q$$

and take for example:

$$\phi:K\to K'\;,\;\;\phi(\sqrt[4]2)=i\sqrt[4]2$$

This extends naturally to a $\;\Bbb Q\,-$ isomorphism

$$\phi\left(a+b\sqrt[4]2+c(\sqrt[4]2)^2+d(\sqrt[4]2)^3\right):=a+bi\sqrt[4]2-c(\sqrt[4]2)^2-di(\sqrt[4]2)^3$$

Yet this isomorphism of fields is **not** a $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)\,-$ isomorphism since

$$\phi\left(\sqrt2\right)=\phi(\sqrt[4]2)^2=\left(i\sqrt[4]2\right)^2=-\sqrt2\neq\sqrt2$$